# Selecting a row in a table and getting the "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" StaleElementReferenceException message in WebDriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium 2/WebDriver for automation.  I have a table and am trying to select a row in it.  When the test runs, I can see the row become highlighted as if it is clicked, but then immediately I get:

> "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM"

error and the test fails.

The code is the following:

```
@Test
public void rowSelection() throws Exception
{
    SeleniumHelper helper = new SeleniumHelper();
    action = new SeleniumActionHelper(driver);

    helper.login();

    String testUrl = navigateToUrl("option/listOptions.xhtml");
    driver.get(testUrl);

    WebElement table = findElementById("tableSection:dataTableWrapped_data");
    List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for (WebElement row : allRows)
        {
            List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            for (WebElement cell : cells)
            {
                WebElement listName = cell.findElement(By.xpath("./*[text()='body_build']"));
                listName.click();
            }
        }
}
```

I have put a Thread.sleep(2000) in front and after the listName.click() action, but neither has helped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you click the element, something obviously changes in the DOM tree and some (or all - depending on the DOM change) of the remembered elements get invalidated / moved. Would iterating backwards help? If not, the only thing you can do is to find one element at a time - it won't be hard to write an XPath expression for it.

Comment: That's where I'm really confused on this.  The row that I am initiating the .click() on becomes highlighted for a brief second before the test fails.  The row could not be highlighted if it was not clicked.  That's also the only action being taken.  I am loading the page and then the next thing is finding and clicking the row in the table.

Comment: Yes! It clicks the first element, that's ok. And then it fails on the second element that should be clicked, because `cells` now holds invalid `td` references.

Comment: Aha!  So if there are two columns in the table, and there are 4 rows have "body_build" in the 1st column and a different value in the 2nd column, the above code is trying to click on all 4 "body_build" cells, which is why the first one works and then it fails, because it's moving to an invalid 2nd row.  You have been a wonderful help!

Comment: If you can resolve the problem, then I'm glad I could help :). If you ended up using the XPath solution to click every element and had trouble writing the right expression, I'll gladly help again.

Answer (score 0):

If you think this is a synchronization issue, you can use `wait.until`:

```
WebElement webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(listName));
```

webElement.click();

And have a break point and check in your application if the locator is getting changed when you do a click operation. If so, you have to consider a better locator.